# Selenium Java trying to click with remote webDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I have to test with selenium a Web Application.

This :

action.moveToElement(webElement,x,y).build().perform();

Is working for 99% of my web elements...

Now I have a web element that is not detected by Selenium IDE.

My boss explains to me that this web element is a kind of plugin. This web element display video from camera.

When I try with Selenium IDE my click isn't detected.

That's why I tryed to do it with action.moveToElement(webElement,x,y).build().perform();

I have a webPath (CSS XPath) for this web element. When I try

webdriver.findElement(By ...).click();

It's not working but I don't have an exception. I guess Selenium do a click and I don't understand why it's not working.

dailymotion.com is like youtube.com (I can't use youtube at work...)

When I try to click on pause on a daylimotion video Selenium IDE don't detect my click. I guess this is the same problem.

I have found this constructor : public Actions(Keyboard keyboard, Mouse mouse) but I don't know how to use it.

I think I can't use java.awt.Robot because I'm working with Selenium grid and I have a lot of node...

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

If can't able to find the webelement you can use coordinates to simulate click..

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  

Action action= builder.moveByOffset(40, 40).build();//change the x and y     coordinate accordingly  

action.perform();
```

Comment: Sorry... my boss explains to me that with the new version of the web application we won't have to click on the video so I can work on other stuff... But I'm quite sure my coordinates are correct. Again, sorry and thanks to try to help me !